# OrangeHrm - Nationality field in Personal Details page transform in a free field

Tags: php, field, orangehrm

I want to modify the Nationality field in Personal Details page to a field that is free to write.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because my website says:

> An internal error occurred. Please contact your system administrator.

I change the files, `viewPersonalDetailsSucess.php`, `EmployeeDao.php`, `EmployeePersonalDetailsForm.php`, `BaseEmployee.class.php`.

I'm missing something? I already change the `hs_hr_employee` table for that column be a `varchar`.

Help me please

Comment: We have no idea what's in those files, show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a better understanding of the error you are getting by checking the log file. it's located in the

`symfony/log/orangehrm.log`

clear the log first (you might need to give write permission to the log file to do this) and recreate the error.

if you still cant figure it out post that log here

Comment: Thanks. I will try to see that file and see whats happen